# I sent myself a test BitCoin, now what? I don't see it, how long do I wait?

Tags: transactions, wallet, testnet

I just created [this](https://tbtc.bitaps.com/b3e8e7dbe13c9939fc3157bef7725282d12594a0e8d14fa73493624ae394f314/mqRkjQjSCCVmsmBzsEQYhwCHEdz9dXRUwW), sending myself 0.01 BitCoin:

```
https://tbtc.bitaps.com/b3e8e7dbe13c9939fc3157bef7725282d12594a0e8d14fa73493624ae394f314/mqRkjQjSCCVmsmBzsEQYhwCHEdz9dXRUwW
```

I've waited for 5 minutes so far and have been checking but nothing:

```
$ bitcoin-cli -testnet getwalletinfo
{
  "walletname": "",
  "walletversion": 169900,
  "balance": 0.00000000,
  "unconfirmed_balance": 0.00000000,
  "immature_balance": 0.00000000,
  "txcount": 0,
  "keypoololdest": ...,
  "keypoolsize": 999,
  "keypoolsize_hd_internal": 1000,
  "paytxfee": 0.00000000,
  "hdseedid": "...",
  "private_keys_enabled": true
}
$ bitcoin-cli -testnet getbalance
0.00000000
$ bitcoin-cli -testnet getunconfirmedbalance
0.00000000
```

Comment: Is your node fully synced with the chain? What does getblockchaininfo say?

Comment: It says a lot, what am I looking for? I don't want to paste in private info :). It says this tho `"blocks": 601014, "headers": 601346`.

Comment: That means you have at least 332 blocks to go before you're fully synchronized.

Comment: Making sure I don't confuse you with my comments: I overlooked that testnet has far more than 600000 blocks, so it seems your node was running mainnet, not testnet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction has more than enough confirmation, so if it doesn't show up, it's probably because your node hasn't catch up with the network yet.

Watch out though, looking at the numbers in your comment up there, the block height is the mainnet one, testnet figures would be a lot higher. Your transaction has been mined on block [1,584,207](https://tbtc.bitaps.com/1584207).

If this is so, it's totally normal your transaction doesn't show up in Bitcoin Core as they are two distinct networks. You should turn off your node with `bitcoin-cli stop`, and turn it back on on testnet with `bitcoind -testnet`. It might take some time if your node need to sync on testnet (but it's usually far faster than mainnet).